# WPF Datagrid- Master Detail showing in same grid like Treeview

Tags: wpf, datagridview, datagrid

We have to show the `sale header` and `sale details` in the same grid. How can we achieve that in the WPF data-grid?

We have a data-set which is having sale-header and sale-detail tables and we have given relations also in the data-set for the sale-header and sale-detail. If I drag and drop the sale-header data-table to a page only sale-header data-grid is created and we are not able to find the sale-detail in the grid.

We want it shown like a tree view. Main tree should have the sale-header and if we drill down the one sale-header row, we should be able to see the full details of its sale-details.

Please help us achieve this with the WPF data-grid.

Comment: You may like to add an image to explain better.

Comment: How would you expect to display two tables in one `DataGrid` control? Take a look in the [DataGrid Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN, to see if you can find that out. Then, if you *still* want to continue asking this question, please edit your question to show what *you* have tried so far... this is *not* a place where you can come to get others to do your work for you.